# this.getOptions not found in react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, babel-loader

When integrating `react-native-firebase` within my native app, I am facing following error while launching the application

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/Users/nikhilfarheen/Documents/ReactComponent/sharespecs/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:46:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikhilfarheen/Documents/ReactComponent/sharespecs/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:41:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

packages installed are

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.20.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "link": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native": "^0.71.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^7.0.0"
 }
```

Tried installing peer dependencies of other packages like webpack but nothing worked

Comment: Please share your `devDependencies` from `package.json`

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@adalo/cli": "^0.0.55",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-art": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.9.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },

Answer (score 0):

You have missed downloading dependencies.

Follow below steps to install dependencies mentioned in their [official doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader)

1. Run `npm uninstall babel-loader`
2. Run `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack`

Comment: still the error is coming